# Docker volumes shared with the Jupyter "lock" the folder

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, docker-desktop, ubuntu-22.04

I'm testing Docker Desktop 4.10 on Ubuntu 22.04.

Let's say that I want to run a Jupyter Notebook:

```
docker run -it \
    -v "${PWD}":/home/jovyan/work \
    -p 8888:8888 \
    jupyter/base-notebook
```

By doing so, I experience the "Permission denied" error while attempting to create a new notebook in the "work" directory.

Starting the notebook with chown options allows me to solve the problem:

```
docker run -it \
    -v "${PWD}":/home/jovyan/work \
    -p 8888:8888 \
    --user root \
    -e CHOWN_HOME="yes" \
    -e CHOWN_HOME_OPTS="-R" \
    jupyter/base-notebook
```

This solution has the drawback of changing the permissions of the folder: I see a padlock on the folder and cannot delete the contents, even after removing the container. In particular, Owner is now "user #100999" and Group "100099".

Looking for alternative solutions with no impact on os-permissions. Thanks

Comment: Removing the container won't remove the content of the Volume, try to delete the volume itself.

Comment: @Shachar297 the command is not creating actual volumes: "docker volume ls" returns an empty table

Comment: docker run -it \
    -v "${PWD}":/home/jovyan/work - should definitely  create a volume

Comment: That creates a bind mount, so it's not managed by Docker. Deleting a bind mount is just deleting the directory on the host that's being mounted.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Docker to use the same owner and group as the directory being mounted.

```
docker run -it \
    -v "${PWD}":/home/jovyan/work \
    -p 8888:8888 \
    --user "$(stat -c '%u:%g' $PWD)" \
    --group-add users \
    jupyter/base-notebook
```

The `stat` command is used to retrieve the user ID and group ID for the current directory's owner.

Comment: This gives me "Permission denied"

Comment: Try it with `--group-add users` as well and also re-create the directory you're mounting, in case previous attempts messed up permissions.

Comment: Still not working while writing files

Comment: You mean you get a permission error when writing a file from JupyterLab? Which directory are you trying to write to? In my test, I was able to write a file to the "work" directory in JupyterLab and then read it back on the host. Note that the root directory in JupyterLab is not part of the bind mount, so files written to the root will not be visible on the host (in fact they won't persist if the container gets deleted).

Comment: Yes I open JupyterLab, navigate into the work directory from the left bar and try to create a new Notebook. Then I get the error

Comment: I did the same and had no problems. Not sure what could be wrong. To completely avoid permission issues, you could use a volume instead of a bind mount. However, this would mean the files would not be conveniently accessible from the host.